# Can I copy the entire scrollback buffer from iTerm2 to the clipboard?

Tags: copy-paste, iterm

I've just run some commands and have several pages of output in iTerm2. Now I'd like to save it somewhere. (I could have piped it to a file, but I didn't think of that.)

Is there an easier way to copy it all to the clipboard that by scrolling back and highlighting for pages?

Answer (score 12):

Oh, right, duh. <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select it all, then <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: There is a setting in iTerm 2 that automatically copies anything selected to the clipboard, making the Command-C unnecessary.

Comment: I did this, but saving a 100M scrollback log through clipboard took iTerm2 about 5 min, and a bit less - to paste it into a text editor. I wish `Cmd-S` saved the buffer directly.

Comment: pbpaste > ~/Desktop/buffer.log  took milliseconds for 17meg file

Answer (score 3):

To capture your history of commands (but not their output):

```
history > ~/Desktop/history.txt
```

If you want output as well, the shell command `script` works as well to capture while you type (but it captures key presses too, so watch out) or iTerm will have some option to save a session, like the stock Terminal's <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

Comment: this will only save your commands, and not their output

Answer (score 0):

Click Shell -> Export text as...

Or press ⌘ + S.